# How to capture submit response in a form created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-jtable

I have a form-iframe combination created inside jTable-create/edit popup to allow upload file:

```
$('#someContainer').jtable({
    ...
    FileUploadDownload: {
        input: function (data) {
            if (typeof data.record  == 'undefined' || !data.record.IsFileLoaded) {
                return '<form target="iframeTarget" class="formUploadFile" action="PostFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="file" onchange="hideButtons(); this.form.submit()" name="myFile"/> </form> <iframe class="upload-iframe" style="display: none;" src="#" name="iframeTarget"></iframe>';
            }
            else {
                return '<a href="DownloadFile?id=' + data.record.Codigo + '">Download</a> <a onclick="ReWriteInputControl(' + data.record.Codigo + ', $(this))">Remove File</a>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My server code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostFile(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
    if (myFile != null && myFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
    ...
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

Everything works.

Now I want to capture the response to re-enable some controls of the popup.
`#jtable-edit-form is the id of a parent div of the popup created by jTable`
`.formUploadFile is a class of the form.`

I tried to do this, but don't work:

```
$("#jtable-edit-form").on("submit", ".formUploadFile", null, function (event) {
    alert("Catch the submit");
    //re-enable some inputs, etc
});
```

Comment: Can you show the markup? Is `#jtable-edit-form` the ID of the form you want to submit?

Comment: Your jquery 'on' Should work fine. Trying changing the selection for 'form'.