# File Upload with JTable and MVC.NET

Tags: java, jquery, model-view-controller

I am creating a simple application for school management. Where I am creating a form for Student registration by teacher. I created it very easily but now I wanted to add student's image also in registration form. 
I tried it by various way given on internet but no luck.
Please help me. below is code what I tried yet for html form

```
img: {
                title: 'Img',
                width: '50%',
                display: function (data) {
                    return "<img src='../content/uploads/" + data.record.id + "/" + data.record.img + "' width='50' >";
                },
                input: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    // data.value will be undefined on create method so we will show only input file tag
                    if (typeof data.value === "undefined") {
                        return '<div><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="upload"/></div>';
                    }
                    else {
                        // on edit method we will show the image and the input file tag
                        return '<div><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="upload"/></div>' +
                           '<div><img style="margin:5px;" src="../content/uploads/' + data.record.qid + '/' + data.value + '"  width="50" /></div>';
                    }
                }
            }

//createAction: '@Model.AddAction', this is commented here fot upload process
            createAction: function (postData) {
                return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
                    debugger;
                    var formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Add")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $dfd.resolve(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

My controller and View path is AppRoot\Areas\Admin\Views\ManageStudent

when I submit this form it gives me error as follows
http://localhost:62997/Admin/function%20(postData)%20%7B%20%20%return%20$.Deferred(function%20($dfd)%20%7B%20%20%var%20formData%20=%20new%20FormData(document.forms[0]);%20%20$.ajax(%7B%20%20url:%20'/Admin/ManageStudent/Add',%20%20type:%20'POST',%20%data:%20formData,%20%20processData:%20false,%20%20%20contentType:%20false,%20%20%dataType:%20'json',%20%20%success:%20function%20(data)%20%7B%$dfd.resolve(data);%20%20%);%207D);%20%%7D

Please help!

Comment: please advice, why path is not created properly

Comment: workdreamer second solution (version change work for me) in below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163895/how-to-upload-image-in-jquery-jtable